# Rsync always failing at the same point

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, windows-server-2019, cifs

I made a script for my Proxmox host to copy its daily backups to another machine (running Windows Server 2019).

The script mounts a CIFS share and runs this rsync command:

```
rsync -aqzP --delete --delete-excluded /mnt/raid/ /mnt/backups --exclude "*.log"
```

It runs for about 6 minutes and then when it tries to copy the `vzdump-qemu-100-2021_05_16-00_00_03.vma.zst` file, it throws an error:

```
rsync: [receiver] close failed on "/mnt/backups/backups/dump/.vzdump-qemu-100-2021_05_16-00_00_03.vma.zst.nrDEvQ": Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(871) [receiver=3.2.3]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

What could be the problem?

*On the windows machine there's all the needed space for the copy.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### How I solved it:

I've discovered [this forgotten post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268240) on the ArchLinux forum, and tried the solution:

It seemed to be a cache problem or something related.

**To have it working, I just added `-o fg,noac,lookupcache=none` to the `mount` command.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into what could cifs not like in that `vzdump-qemu-100-2021_05_16-00_00_03.vma.zst` file.

- Is the file created on remote volume ? It is empty of partially copied ?
- Is the size of the file supported by the remote filesystem or by cifs protocol ?

Aslo if the file is usable by rsync :

- Is the file accessible for the user running rsync (file rights, file locked by another process, etc.)

At last, if i'd not have results with this, i'd try to increase rsync verbosity to get more details ont the error :

`rsync -aqzPvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ...`

Comment: The file is created but Proxmox says that its size is 11.24GB but on Windows explorer it says 10.98, so I can think that's partially copied.
Before the file that causes the error, there are other backups that follows the same format and are copied successfully.